# laravel @json automatically convert time from IST to GMT

Tags: json, laravel

In my laravel project i have an array of created_at

```
    $dates = Lead::where('created_at', '>', now()->subDays(30)->endOfDay())
        ->orderby('created_at', 'desc')
        ->select('created_at')
        ->get()->toArray();
```

when i convert that array with `@json($dates)` in blade it automatically get converted from  IST to GMT. why is this happening? how do i prevent this ?

Comment: It's probably not converting to GMT, but UTC instead. Also why is this tagged with JavaScript?

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry accidentally added that tags

Comment: @evolutionxbox if it is converting to utc how do i prevent it ?

Comment: I don't know. Have you set the default timezone https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-date-time-operations?

Comment: @evolutionxbox . default timezone is already set as ist.

Comment: Can you post the part where you set the timezone?